# SQLite вычислить разницу между двумя строками с условием

Tags: sqlite, select

У меня есть таблица tb1

| id(KEY) | idprod | allregion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 28 |
| 2 | 34 | 142 |
| 3 | 44 | 3 |
| 4 | 44 | 16 |
| 5 | 65 | 1132 |
| 6 | 65 | 768 |

Мне нужно вычислить разницу значений allregion между одинаковыми idprod и поместить это в столбик diff. Должно получиться вот так:

| id(KEY) | idprod | allregion | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 28 | 0 |
| 2 | 34 | 142 | 114[142-28] |
| 3 | 44 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 44 | 16 | 13[16-3] |
| 5 | 65 | 1132 | 0 |
| 6 | 65 | 768 | -364[768-1132] |

*[в скобках указан пример вычислений]

Мой код

```
SELECT id, idprod, allregion, 
CASE WHEN idprod = LAG(idprod, 1) OVER (ORDER BY idprod desc, id desc) 
THEN (allregion - LAG(allregion, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id desc)) ELSE '0' 
END AS diff
FROM tb1
```

выдает таблицу с нулевыми значениями allregion

| id(KEY) | idprod | allregion | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 34 | 0 | 114[142-28] |
| 3 | 44 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 44 | 0 | 13[16-3] |
| 5 | 65 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 65 | 0 | -364[768-1132] |

и я не могу понять почему, помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [`PARTITION BY`](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) и функцию [`IFNULL()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull)

```
SELECT id, idprod, allregion, 
IFNULL(allregion - LAG(allregion, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY idprod),0) AS diff
FROM tb1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, заработало)